# Where does $\sin(x^2)$ cross the $x$ axis where $0\leq x \leq 18$?

Tags: trigonometry

One of my friends gave me the puzzle, and I can obviously figure it out with a graphic calculator, but I can't find the way to do it without a calculator. Any advice?

Comment: A starting point would be to figure out where $\sin(y)$ crosses the axis for $0 \le y \le 18^2$.

Comment: And since $18^2=324$ and $100\pi\approx314.159$ we arrive in $103$ intersections without calculator.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
 \sin (x^2) &= 0 \\
 x^2 &= n \pi, ~~n \in \mathbb{Z} \\
 x&= \sqrt{n \pi}, ~~n \in \mathbb{Z_+}
\end{align*}
Using that $0 \leq x \leq 18$, we need 
\begin{align*}
 0 &\leq \sqrt{n \pi} \leq 18 \\
 0 &\leq n \pi \leq 18^2=324 \\
 0 &\leq n \leq 324/\pi \approx 103.1
\end{align*}
Thus $x=\sqrt{n \pi}$ for any $n \in \{ 0, 1, 2, \dots, 103 \}$.